# LWJGL: pass OpenGL context between threads

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have two threads running in my program. When I try to use OpenGL functions in the thread that is not my main, it throws an IllegalStateException:No OpenGL context is current in the current thread. So my question is, how do I pass the context from the main thread to a different thread? I am using LWJGL 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it but I'm not 100% sure it's the best way to do it. You have to call GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(MemoryUtil.NULL); in the thread you want to depart from, then call GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); GLContext.createFromCurrent(); from the thread you want to switch to.

Comment: Usually you just create 2 contexts. Try googling opengl shared context.

Comment: What you do works too, but will be very slow if you need to change current context often.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mean showing how to create two different contexts? There are literally no examples I could find. I've tried GLContext.createFromCurrent(); and since that returns a GLContext object, I thought that I could just call it twice and store the GLContext in two different variables, and call GL.setCurrent(otherContext) in the other thread, but none of my OGL calls have any effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not 100% clear, is the windowID for the window your want to switch to, its own ID or is the ID of the previous window? Also GLContext.createFromCurrent(); is replaced with GL.createCapabilities()?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/tree/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/opengl/multithread). It uses a [Drawable](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable.java) that you can use in your two Java Threads. I'm not entirely sure if it still works since a lot of this class is associated with LWJGL 2. I'll test it soon and let you know if this or your method is more efficient (Gonna create a tiny micro-benchmark :) .